# Launch browser window with parameters using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, window

Trying develop tool using Node.js that will open new browser window with provided url and needed parameters.

Tool should work like window.open() methods.

I mean I need to hide menu bar, set size and etc.

Tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/open .

but no idea how to pass parameters like "menubar=no"

```
const open = require('open');

(async () => {
  await open('https://google.com', {app: ['chrome', '--incognito']});
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the flags:

```
--app="http://example.com" --force-app-mode
```

Comment: can you please clarify? Have no idea where to put this

Comment: {app: ['chrome', '--force-app-mode']} tried like that, nothing changed. I guess I'm doing it wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
open.openApp(open.apps.chrome, {arguments: ['--app=https://google.com']});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your answer and add a little textual explanation why and how it works and how it differs from the other answer.